# display the row count of a table in a label.text

Tags: objective-c

Hi i have a table and want to display how many items are in the table in a label.text so convert the row count into a text string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to count the model ( array or dictionary count) and form a string:

```
NSString *rowCountString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[yourArray count]]; //or dictionary

//if this is for osx 64 bit use %ld instead of %d
```

then show the string  in the label.

```
yourLabel.text = rowCountString; //UILabel ios

[yourLabel setStringValue:rowCountString];//NSTextField as label osx
```